# How would you like Aviation Stack Exchange to deal with Drone/UAV questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

I am a moderator over at [Aviation Stack Exchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/), and we have recently been [discussing how we should deal with drone/UAV questions](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/do-we-have-a-clear-policy-on-drone-questions), I think in no small part because we have started noticing a marked increase in this subject on the site.

There is some inconsistency in how these get dealt with; one of a few things tend to happen:

- They get answered, sometimes very well. This is especially true with the kind of aerodynamics ones as we have a lot of people pretty knowledgeable on that subject
- They get closed as off topic - usually true of the microelectronics sort of questions that are very specific to RC aircraft
- They get migrated to Drones - often the ones on the actual acts of flying, and sometimes the system ones (again like electronics)

In the linked meta post above, I have made my suggestions how I think we should deal with drone questions on Aviation, but I wanted to hear from your community how you would like us to handle this too.

Would you like more questions migrated to Drones.SE? Would you like *all* questions migrated? Would you like none?

Answer (score 5):

It's a great question... I speak or myself when I say that I think here we will accept any question which is on-topic here ("Questions about any type of drone or unmanned aerial vehicle (UAV) including underwater drones" is pretty broad...). We're in a slightly different position than you in that aviation of drones is clearly on-topic here and consequently the only reason we would migrate to you would be if someone asked a question about full-size aeroplanes or the such like, but that's unlikely simply given the name of the site.

In other words I think anything you migrate over is likely to get accepted. Obviously I don't need to say that we don't want to be a dumping ground for every mediocre question which contains the word "drone," but I don't foresee that ever being a problem ;)

As far as what to migrate over... I think that's largely up to your community. Not being active on aviation I have no idea whatsoever what the attitude is toward drones. I'd simply be guessing from the current vote counts on the post you linked when I say that it seems that the community generally agrees that if there is no crossover with large aircraft the question is off-topic and thus should be migrated.

One comment would be that if you do determine that you migrate drone questions not related to aviation generally, it would be great to leave guidance to the community that when flagging for migration, to leave a comment explaining to the OP not to cross-post since migration is incoming.

Short answer, I think as far as site-scope is concerned I doubt anything you migrate over is going to get rejected. As far as what to migrate, I think it's really up to you.

Comment: Agreed! Our talent pool for answering questions is regrettably small, but we would welcome any migrations or redirections for UAV-related inquiries.

Comment: Could you add a [tag:status-review] to this question inline with the instructions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374186/our-site-just-graduated-launched-left-beta-do-we-need-to-do-anything/379931#379931) for setting up a migration path